# Remove spaces from the text and combine them into a single text

Tags: postgresql

I have a text APPLE 23 under a field Fruits. I would like to remove the spaces and get a text as APPLE23. How to i do that in postgres?

-Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
replace(mystring,' ','') to get rid of spaces in the string.
```

Comment: cool ... sometimes it's as easy as that!

Answer (score 0):

To replace characters (as opposed to whole strings), [`translate()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) is even faster:

```
SELECT translate (mystring, ' ', '')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will keep this in mind.